# Vue CLI 3 target build lib exclude shared styling

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I am currently working on a Vue.js project where i use the Vue CLI 3 to build components in lib mode like this: `vue-cli-service build --no-clean --target lib --name ComponentName.vue`. The components can then be used any website if registered in a Vue instance.

However, the website contains it's own stylesheets and the component too. To develop and see the actual styles applied to component i have to pull in these (shared) styles in every component i develop. Therefore they are also in the compiled stylesheets after building the component using the command stated above (`vue-cli-service build`).

My question: Can i exclude the (shared) styles when building the component? I can't find anything about it in the docs (https://cli.vuejs.org/). If somebody could provide the answer or a (Webpack) workaround that would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How may components are we talking? Could you delete the components styles and then build without styling so that you could apply styles from the top?

Comment: I have not seen any options to neglect styling ...

Comment: We are talking about many components (50+). I could off course delete the styles before building. But it will be better if styles (@import) imported from a certain folder could be excluded when building a component.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly but there is an option to have these styles inline in the components itself, which would be much easier for development.

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#app

`dist/myLib.css:`

Extracted CSS file (*can be forced into inlined by setting* `css: { extract: false }` **in vue.config.js**)

Comment: Seen that. It's not what i am looking for. Every built component should consist of a .css, .js and a .html file. The .css-file should only contain component-specific styles and all shared styles should excluded from this file.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along!